# Make master package to fail in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a master package that has a sequence container which contains 2 child packages (execute package task) in SSIS.
I would like to make the whole master package to fail if one of child packages task fail. how can I do this? what SSIS property should I change ? should I set `failparentonfailure = true` for each child package task?

Comment: Execute Package Task A and Execute Package Task B both fire simultaneous. If A fails or B fails, the master itself fails. Are you experiencing something different?

Comment: yes. task B   was still going ( it has an oledb data load  bulk insert ) even though task A was failed... at the end the task B completed ,but the status of master package returns as fail. why SSIS did not trying to kill the bulk insert process in task B?